# Odd iOS memory management experience

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory, hardware

We were testing our app, on the first generation iPad, using the profile tool, which uses a lot of memory on the iPad, in Xcode and found that our app had slow memory deallocation (It took more than 1 minute to deallocate 20 MB). However, in our code we properly deallocate memory. We then monitored some professional 3rd party apps (Chrome and Flipboard) and noticed those apps also had the same rate of deallocation.

Does iOS or iPad 1 have slow memory deallocation or perhaps the profiler interferes with iOS's memory deallocation?

We are using the lastest iOS version. And yes, in real world usage our app's performance will be affected by the slow deallocation of memory

We measured the rate of deallocation by loading the app and waiting for the memory to stabilize and then loading media or a view and waiting for that to stabilize then we go back to the original view and see how load it takes to deallocate the previous view/media. Which goes at a rate of (less than 20 MB every 1 minute). The app will never go back to it's original memory usage, the usage after opening the app and waiting for it to stabilize, when on the startup view.

Comment: What do you mean by "slow deallocation?"  Was app performance impacted?  What version of iOS are you running on that iPad?

Comment: How are you measuring deallocation rate?

Answer (score 1):

> We measured the rate of deallocation by loading the app and waiting for the memory to stabilize and then loading media or a view and waiting for that to stabilize then we go back to the original view and see how load it takes to deallocate the previous view/media.

This is not a useful benchmark.  Okay, so you allocated some memory.  Then you told the OS that you didn't need it any more.  Fine so far.  It's often not going to bother doing much about it unless it needs the memory elsewhere.  It makes more sense to keep a cache so that if you need it again, it's available quicker.  You aren't measuring anything useful - you're measuring how long it takes the system to need the memory elsewhere, not how long is *necessary* to deallocate it.  Common sense should tell you that a minute to deallocate 20MB is not correct.

I suggest you come up with a benchmark that measures what you are *actually* interested in.  How would your application be affected by slow deallocation?  Are you sure you aren't inadvertently using that as a poor substitute for a factor you really are interested in?

Comment: Agreed. I assume that MrHappyOne is using the Activity Monitor instrument to measure usage. The memory listed here is not particularly meaningful. The much more useful and meaningful instrument is Allocations. If this is taking a long time to come down, then you likely have an actual problem in your code (or in a high-level library such as WebKit). Your discussion of the OS-level memory management (i.e. that the OS will not quickly reclaim memory unless it needs it) is spot-on.

Comment: We did do a few other memory tests, however I didn't want to add too much information to a question I thought was dead. Our app crashes due to memory issues often and iOS fails to deallocate enough memory when it is required to prevent crashing. Some of our tests had high memory stress and iOS failed to deallocate. I am going to test our app, and other apps, out on an iPad 2 and see if I get the same results. Also remember the iOS profiler utilizes a good bit of memory.

Comment: Could it not simply be that you're using too much memory?  Apple tells you to be very conservative with memory use, and iOS doesn't guarantee any particular amount of memory for your application.  Any given application is not entitled to all available memory.  If you're positive that iOS is not allocating you memory when it is supposed to, I suggest you use a tech support incident to talk to Apple about it.

Comment: We are conservative with memory and deallocate whatever the user isn't seeing and what the app isn't using. I am stress testing the app, without the profiler, on the iPad 2 and it seems to handle okay with just our app running. I will try testing the app with tensive use and more application running and see how it handles memory. With the profiler, it crashes with intensive use.

Comment: It will crash on the iPad 2 with other app running in the background after intensive use. On the iPad 2 it keep getting really low memory (5MB available) but mostly managed to keep operating. We tested it out again on the iPad 1 without profiler hogging resources and it only seems to crash after intensive use.

Answer (score 0):

If you do release memory when needed (i. e. you make the effort to minimize the time during which memory is allocated), then you don't have to worry about "slow deallocation" (whatever this nonsense word means).

Don't overestimate a profiler's abilities.

Comment: @MrHappyOne: This is not an accurate understanding of how memory management works. The hardware is not involved at this level in allocation. You may be seeing artifacts from autorelease pools, or allocations from the frameworks undergoing their own lifecycles.

Comment: @quixoto we are deallocating properly and I assume Flipboard and Chrome are too. The deallocation process is just very slow.

Comment: @quixoto Hardware does play a role in memory management especially when using DDR1 ram. However, iOS seems to be the issue as it manages memory allocation and deallocation, BUT we as I have stated before we are deallocating properly and I assume Chrome and Flipboard are too.

Comment: @MrHappyOne, the Wikipedia link is condescending and insulting.  Please don't do that.